# How to write System.Diagnostic.Process output without blocking execution?

Tags: .net, process

i'm trying to write a simple software who play karaoke in Mono Gtk / .NET. 
I simply want to run via shell something like "timidity filename.kar" (timidity is a software synth). 
I want to write timidity output into a textview, but the problem is that if i run this code, timidity start to 'play' but the app exits

protected virtual void OnBtnPlayClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string parms = filechooser.Filename;
        string output = "";
        string error = string.Empty;

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("timidity", parms);

    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Process reg;
    reg = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

    reg.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
reg.BeginOutputReadLine();     // HERE THE APP GO CRASH

}

  private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, 
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // Collect the sort command output.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {                
            txtOutput.Buffer.Text =txtOutput.Buffer.Text + outLine.Data;

        }
    }
```

Where i'm wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: This code has been edited after the answer has been checked and is conform to the answer, so it may still crash, and the answer may be wrong. Is this possible to comment about how this has been resolved, and what was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to `ReadToEnd` of the spawned process's standard output, which will block until that process closes its standard output stream. In this case, this will be when the process terminates.

What you need to do instead is redirect the standard output and read chunks out of it as they become available using [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx).

For example:

```
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
reg = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
reg.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => 
                          Console.WriteLine("received output: {0}", args.Data);
reg.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. So i redirect the output with compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
compiler.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()); but anyway my app go blocking !

Comment: @stighy: You cannot use `ReadToEnd`, period. I edited the answer, see the example at the linked MSDN page (I added a shorter version here too).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work fully async I suggest something like what I detailed here in another post like this, seperate thread and event driven.

[Execute command promt process asnyc and get result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804725/execute-command-promt-process-asnyc-and-get-result/7812984#7812984)