# How to send commands to cmd from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I'm Developing application in VB.NEt(Visual studio 2017) I wan to send some commands to CMD and receive output in multiline textbox How can i do it? and only one window of cmd should be visible

Comment: I suggest that you should run a batch file instead from vb

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381405

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute command promt process asnyc and get result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804725/execute-command-promt-process-asnyc-and-get-result)

Comment: [How do I get output from a command to appear in a control on a form in real-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680382/how-do-i-get-output-from-a-command-to-appear-in-a-control-on-a-form-in-real-time?answertab=active#tab-top). There's a sample project attached. The code is  C#, but it's quite simple to read/translated and the notes there could be useful.

Comment: This one is in VB.Net language [How To Output Shell Command To a RichTextBox In Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312990/how-to-output-shell-command-to-a-richtextbox-in-visual-basic?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 3):

A bit of googling...

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
    Dim CMDThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
    CMDThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub CMDAutomate()
        Dim myprocess As New Process
        Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        StartInfo.FileName = "cmd" 'starts cmd window
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True '<---- if you want to not create a window
        StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'required to redirect
        myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
        myprocess.Start()
        Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
        Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
        SW.WriteLine(txtCommand.Text) 'the command you wish to run.....
        SW.WriteLine("exit") 'exits command prompt window
        txtResults.Text = SR.ReadToEnd 'returns results of the command window
        SW.Close()
        SR.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

the previous answer is nearly correct but will bring up a cross-thread error. Put the return text from the cmd output into a variable and then call the string after the Sub in the button click as below...

on a form create a button called: btnPowerShSend,
create two text boxes with the multi-line property ticked, called:
txtResults &
txtScript

```
        Public Class Form1
        Dim retText As String
    
        Private Sub BtnPowerShSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPowerShSend.Click
            Dim CMDThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
            CMDThread.Start()
            txtResults.Text = retText 'returns results of the command window
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub CMDAutomate()
            Dim myprocess As New Process
            Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
            StartInfo.FileName = "cmd" 'starts cmd window
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True '<---- if you want to not create a window
            StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'required to redirect
            myprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
            myprocess.Start()
            Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
            Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
            SW.WriteLine(txtScript.Text) 'the command you wish to run.....
            SW.WriteLine("exit") 'exits command prompt window
    
            retText = SR.ReadToEnd.ToString
    
            SW.Close()
            SR.Close()
        End Sub
    End Class
```